# SQLite refusing to use better index?

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [Groups] ([Group] VARCHAR(50) NULL, [ArtNum] INTEGER NULL, [ID] VARCHAR(50)  NULL, [Time] INTEGER);
CREATE INDEX [GroupTime]   ON [Groups] ([Group], [Time] DESC);
CREATE INDEX [GroupArtNum] ON [Groups] ([Group], [ArtNum]);
```

I would like optimize the following query:

```
 SELECT `ID` FROM `Groups` WHERE `Group`=? ORDER BY `Time` DESC LIMIT 1
```

The problem is that SQLite insists on using the `GroupArtNum` index instead of the `GroupTime` index. `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` prints the following:

```
SEARCH TABLE Groups USING INDEX GroupArtNum (Group=?) (~10 rows)
USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

What's interesting is that if I try to sort by `ArtNum` instead of `Time`, it runs very quickly.

I have only (64-bit) integers in the `Time` column, same as with `ArtNum`.

Comment: Have you tried running [`ANALYZE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html)?

Comment: If `ANALYZE` does not fix this, putting `Time` into the query *should* trick it.  Something like this: `WHERE Group=? AND Time>=0`.  There may be more elegant solutions, however.

Comment: ANALYZE worked, thanks!!! Please repost as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `ANALYZE` (which might or might not help in any specific case); or
2. use the `INDEXED` clause to force using a specific index (although the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_indexedby.html) warns against doing this):

   ```
   SELECT ID FROM Groups INDEXED BY GroupTime WHERE ...
   ```
3. or update to SQLite 3.7.15 (when it's released), which has query planner optimizations that make it recognize that using `GroupTime` is more efficient.